# If $I+J=R$, where $R$ is a commutative rng, prove that $IJ=I\cap J$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, rngs

So I basically have to prove what is on the title.

> Given $R$ a commutative rng (a ring that might not contain a $1$), with the property that $I+J=R$, (where $I$ and $J$ are ideals) we have to prove that $IJ=I\cap J$.

One inclusion is easy. If $x\in IJ$, then $x=\sum a_ib_i$ where $a_i\in I$ and $b_i\in J$. Thus for any fixed $i$, we have that since $a_i\in I$, we have that $a_ib_i\in I$, and the same argument shows that $a_ib_i\in J$, thus $\sum a_ib_i\in I$ and $\sum a_ib_i\in J$, this means that $x=\sum a_ib_i\in I\cap J$, and thus $IJ\subset I\cap J$.

I am having troubles proving the other inclusion. Any comments?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, ins't this false for general commutative rngs? Consider $\mathbb Z$ with the normal addition and multiplication $\cdot$ defined by $a\cdot b=0,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z$. Then $(2)$ and $(3)$ are comaximal ideals (since we can write $x$ as $2a+3b$ in integers with regular multiplication so as $2 + \cdots + 2 + 3 + \cdots + 3$ in our rng), $(2)\cap (3)=(6)\neq (0)$ yet clearly $(2)(3)=0$.

Comment: Im thinking its false as well with $I=4\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=6\mathbb{Z}$ and $R=2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: what happens if the ring R is not Commutative??

Comment: @user8795 : see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222474/assume-r-is-commutative-if-ij-r-prove-that-ij-i-cap-j-provide-a-count?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is only necessarily true for commutative rings with $1$. In this case, you can argue that
$$I\cap J\subseteq (I\cap J)R=(I\cap J)(I+J)=I(I\cap J)+ J(I\cap J)\subseteq IJ+ IJ=IJ$$

A counterexample to the statement for general rngs is given by endowing the group $\mathbb Z$ with the zero product, that is defining $a\cdot b=0,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z$. The ideals $(2)$ and $(3)$ are still comaximal, as for any $x\in\mathbb Z$ we can write $x=a\times 2+b\times 3$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, where $\times$ denotes regular multiplication, and $a\times 2=2+\cdots+2\in(2)$ where addition is performed $a$ times, and similarly $b\times 3\in (3)$. But $(2)\cap (3)=(6)\neq (0)$, yet clearly $(2)(3)=(0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Perhaps a little easier example its just $R$ be the even numbers, $I$ the multiples of $4$ and $J$ the multiples of $6$.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion whether or not it had a $1$. I got it out from Dummit and Foote, and they usually have rings without a $1$, but in the beggining of the section they said to consider only unital rings.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre The author mentions that $1\in R$ at the beginning of the **Exercises** of this section, but not at the beginning of the section.

Answer (score 0):

Good job on the first implication. For the latter:

I claim that

$$I \cap J \subset IJ$$

$\textbf{Proof of claim:}$

Let $x \in I \cap J$. And note that since $R=I+J$, one can write

$$1=a+b ; \space \text{some $a \in I, b \in J$}$$

Then multiplying through by $x$, one has

$$x=xa+xb \in IJ.$$

Thus $IJ = I \cap J$ given that $I+J=R$. If this is not the case that the sum of the ideals is the whole of the ring, then for a counterexample take $I=(2), J=(4)$ (and $R=\Bbb{Z}$). Then $IJ=(8)$ but $I \cap J = (4)$ and it is clear to see $(8) \subsetneq (4)$ and equality doesnt hold as $8 \nmid 4$.

$\square$