# Chinese remainder theorem does not hold in non commutative case

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Consider the ring $R$ of non commutative real polynomials in $X$ and $Y$. Denote by $I$ the principal two-sided ideal generated by $X$ and $J$ the principal two-sided ideal generated by $XY+1$. Then $I+J=R$, but $I∩J≠IJ$.
I understand the first part since $1\in I+J$, but I could not show $I∩J≠IJ$. Any example to show? Thanks

Comment: $R$ is not clear, what do you mean by "non-commutative real polynomials in $X$ and $Y$" ? For me, "real polynomials in $X$ and $Y$" sounds like $R=\mathbb R[X,Y]$ which is commutative. Maybe you mean $R$ non commutative, and consider $R[X,Y]$ ?

Comment: This is the exact wording taken from a lecture note. I think you are right in interpretation. Any example to show. Thanks

Comment: I searched online, there do exist non commutative polynomials in which variables do not commute. I think the author means that R<x,y>

Comment: I think non commutative here means that $XY \neq YX$. The base ring is just the reals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key idea here is that if the ring doesn't commute, we don't necessarily have $IJ=JI$ whereas $I \cap J= J \cap I$. So consider the element $(XY+1)\cdot X$. It is in $I \cap J$ but not in $IJ$ hence $I \cap J \neq IJ$.

Comment: I feel myself so dumb. You made it so simple. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it not in $IJ$?

Comment: Ah, I see. We can quotient further by $X\left(XY+1\right)$ and $Y\left(XY+1\right)$; this will kill every element of $IJ$. The quotient has a confluent rewriting system $XXY \to -X$ and $YXY \to -Y$, but the element $\left(XY+1\right)X$ is reduced modulo this quotient.